# Console windows that cannot be killed by closing or via Task Manager

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005, console, taskmanager

When I run a test harness through the Visual Studio 2005 debugger, it creates a console window every time I run it.

In the past, the console window would close automatically when the test harness process terminated, but now I'm finding that the console window is hanging around afterwards.

After the test harness terminates:

- I cannot close the console window by clicking the close (x) button on the top-right
- The test harness process doesn't exist anymore in Task Manager

So I cannot seem to kill these console windows.

Does anyone know:

1. How these console windows can exist without a managing process?
2. How can I can kill these console windows?

Rebooting is obviously an option, but there must be another way.

Comment: Does it go away if you kill VS

Comment: @rerun - No, this doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried using Process Explorer from SysInternals? if the process exists it should show it, and enable you to kill it more effectively than through the standard task manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known bug in windows, introduced with KB978037 security patch.

You can find out more here
http://blogs.msdn.com/debugger/archive/2010/03/11/help-my-console-windows-won-t-go-away.aspx

and here
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/e6d4a4f5-7002-401a-90e1-6174d7f9e3ca

Answer (score -3):

In Windows, "Administrator" is not the highest level user. Some processes/files/directories are only accessible by the "SYSTEM" user.
See: http://hackspc.com/how-to-become-the-system-user-in-windows-xp/

This may be the reason why it is unkillable.